# PostgreSQL INSERT using Python

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm trying to upload a file in binary form to PostgreSQL via python

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO resultdata(data) VALUES(%s)", (psycopg2.Binary(data),))
```

So it uploads it in strange way: when i try to view it in db it just spaces

Comment: What type is `data` in the database?

Comment: Aside: Putting files into your database probably isn't the best approach for whatever you're trying to do.

Comment: @Mureinik data = f.read()

Comment: @Maxim_CH, Mureinik is asking what the column type of the `data` column in the `resultdata` table is.

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by _view in the db_? view it through some client like dbeaver or datagrip?

Comment: Oh, sorry... its TEXT

Comment: @solarc well i use select * from resultdata

Comment: @Maxim_CH I mean in which software do you run that query? I think the problem is not that the data is not getting stored but that the viewer doesn't know how to show it. If it is a binary file then all the bits that are not printable characters might show as whitespace. Try doing a query from python and then write the data to a new file and see if it is different to the old file.

Comment: @solarc Yeah you are right, I was trying to do it through terminal but in dbeaver it's shows normally. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just I figured that. Try this code:

```
 cur.execute('INSERT INTO resultdata(data) VALUES (%s)', (data,))
 cur.fetchall()
```

Actually, there no use psycopg2.Binary(data) and there already given an imported with psycopg2.